# Function returns zero if parameter has more than 7 zeros

Tags: haskell

I wrote a haskell function which counts pi number with precision given as parameter:

```
mojePi :: Integer -> Float
mojePi x = sqrt $ 6 * mySum x
    where
        mySum 1 = 1
        mySum x = sum $ map (1/) $ map (**2) [y,y-1..1]
            where
                y = fromInteger x
```

If I run this function with `10000000`(7 zeros) it works fine, but with `100000000`(8 zeros) and more it immediately returns `0`.
Why does it happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's why:

```
> let y :: Float ; y = fromInteger (100000000 :: Integer)
> y == y-1
True
> [y, y-1 .. 1]
[]
```

Basically, a `Float` can not count from 10^8 downwards to 1, with unit steps.

Rounding errors make `y` and `y-1` the same number, hence the notation `[y,y-1 .. 1]` is interpreted as an *increasing* sequence, like e.g. `[10,10 .. 1]`. Since the starting value is already over `1`, no element gets put in the output list.

Quoting from the [Haskell 2010 report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch6.html#x13-1310006.3.4):

> The sequence `enumFromThenTo e1 e2 e3` is the list `[e1,e1 + i,e1 + 2i,…e3]`, where the increment, `i`, is `e2 − e1`. If the increment is
>   positive or zero, the list terminates when the next element would be
>   greater than `e3`; the list is empty if `e1  >  e3`. If the increment is
>   negative, the list terminates when the next element would be less than
>   `e3`; the list is empty if `e1  <  e3`.

Arguably, Haskell should have different notations for increasing and decreasing ranges. For `[y, y-1 .. 1]`, I guess `repeat y` would be a less surprising output than `[]`.

Comment: Might be worth explaining `[y,y-1 .. 1]` being `[]`. Section [6.3.4 The Enum Class](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch6.html#x13-1310006.3.4) goes into some detail. I wasn't aware of all this behavior.

Comment: @Alec Indeed, I think I also figured it out right now! Added.