# Why Does Haskell's Range Syntax use First and Then rather than First and Step?

Tags: haskell, range

I've just started learning Haskell, and was surprised by the behaviour of ranges.

I am aware that `[1, 2 .. 10]` is syntactic sugar for `enumFromThenTo 1 2 10`.

From other programming languages, (for instance Python) I'm used to ranges being specified with *first*, *last* and *step* arguments, such that Haskell's *then* is equivalent to *first+step* in Python.

Why does Haskell use *then*, rather than *step* to define the spacing between values in the sequence?

Comment: IMO, _step_ is better. Using _then_ sometimes can lead to unpleasant surprises when floating points are involved: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42773864/function-returns-zero-if-parameter-has-more-than-7-zeros

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that e.g. Python's range specifier is a *function*:

```
>>> range(1, 12, 2)
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11]
```

Haskell is aiming to provide syntax that literally looks like you might write out the list for another human, writing `..` instead of the "obvious" pattern:

```
ghci> [1, 3 .. 11]
[1,3,5,7,9,11]
```

Another point (raised by Carl in a comment on leftaroundabout's answer) is that the sequence syntax can be used on non-numeric types, where there isn't such an easy way of writing a "step":

```
ghci> ['a', 'f' .. 'z']
"afkpuz"
```

Comment: Agreed, even if I believe `Enum` types should be isomorphic to a segment of `Int`, since we have `toEnum / fromEnum`, so an `Int` stepping should be well defined. Making floating point types to be `Enum`s looks as a mistake to me. (Or, alternatively, those two functions should be moved to another class)

Comment: @chi Yeah, there are definitely times I want a type to be enumerable but don't have a good isomorphism to Int. I'd rather `toEnum` / `fronEnum` were in a different class; you can't really use them sensibly while being polymorphic in Enum, you have to know more about the specific type in use. But mostly I find I only use Enum stuff when I do know what I'm working with, so it's not really critical.

Answer (score 5):

Just building on what Ben and Carl said:

the functions defined in Enum are polymorphic, e.g.

```
λ> :t enumFromThenTo
enumFromThenTo :: Enum a => a -> a -> a -> [a]
```

and by defining them as "first, second, last", we can use the same polymorphic type parameter `a` for all the arguments!

If we defined them as "first, last, step", then the `step` parameter might have a different type from the other two.

- For an integer sequence, the step is also an integer - no problem.
- For a character sequence, the step is again an integer - so maybe we could fix the type of `step` to be some integral type? (But which one?)
- But no - for a float sequence, the step also needs to be a float!

So we'd need (I think!) to add another type variable to the Enum typeclass, which would make it a lot more complex, and (probably - haven't checked) needs a GHC extension rather than standard Haskell.

Comment: An alternative would be to say `['A'..'Z', succ . succ . succ]` for ` ['A', 'D' .. 'Z']` but it is of course harder to read and can more easily be written with `iterate`

Comment: `Enum` is really weird, since `toEnum  . (+ k) . fromEnum` is well typed, hence an `Int` stepping seems always reasonable. Floating point types, IMO should not have been made into `Enum` (or otherwise the `toEnum,fromEnum` should belong to another class)

Comment: @chi `toEnum . (+k) . fromEnum` may be well-typed; but that doesn't mean it expresses all the behaviors you want. For that reason, I think this answer's example of `Float`/`Double` is a good one: there are steps that are currently supported that do not fit into your proposed pattern.

Comment: Your answer got me thinking that such sequences can be defined over an affine space. Elements of a sequence would be points of this affine space, and the step of a sequence would be a vector from the vector space which this affine space is defined over.

Answer (score 4):

I agree, IMO start-step-end would have been the better convention. However, start-then-end is more commonly found in pure maths contexts, and that's Haskell's heritage.

Note that you can very easily achieve by hand

- Start-step-end:

  ```
  takeWhile (<end+step/2) $ iterate (+step) start
  ```
- Start-step-count:

  ```
  take count $ iterate (+step) start
  ```

Whereas start-then-end requires to first compute the step by hand

```
let step = then - start
in takeWhile (< end+step/2) $ iterate (+step) start
```

so it kind of makes sense to add syntactic sugar / standard functions for the expression that's harder to implement manually.

Comment: Another really key point is that it's not restricted to numeric types.